# MySQL regular expression to select the last integer in the string

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL database table that contains column `run` that is an integer and another column `filename` that is a varchar with typical values like RUN0001.FTS or 3DS0231.FTS or 3RUN0010.FTS

I need to check the values in the `run` and `filename` columns. The prescription is I extract the last integer (without leading zeroes) before the dot character (.) in the `filename` column, and compare it to the value of the `run` column. How do I write a select statement to do this comparison to return the rows that will not have the matching integers?

For example, a regular expression I am trying to build would extract 1 from RUN0001.FTS, or 231 from 3DS0231.FTS, or 10 from 3RUN0010.FTS and then compare it to the value in the `run` column, and return the primary key if the two don't match.

In Python I would manipulate the variable filename = '3RUN0010.FTS' like so:

```
import re
filename = '3RUN0010.FTS'
fileRunNumber = re.findall('\d+', filename)
runNumber = int(fileRunNumber[-1])
print "The integer I want is", runNumber
```

How do I do this in as a MySQL statement?

Thanks,
Aina.

Comment: In MySQL the only thing you can do with a regular expression is test whether something matches it. You can't use it to extract parts of a string. There are third-party UDFs that can do this, search for them with Google.

Comment: Does the pattern always end in four digits?

Comment: @Tim, yes, it always does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(col, INSTR(col, '.') - 4, 4) AS UNSIGNED) AS theNumber
FROM yourTable
```

**Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (col varchar(55));
INSERT INTO yourTable (col)
VALUES
    ('RUN0001.FTS'),
    ('3DS0231.FTS'),
    ('3RUN0010.FTS');
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Great, this has totally solved my problem and is exactly what I needed, thanks, Tim!